# Chrome “Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it” error

Tags: javascript

```
window.close();//false

window.open(location, '_self', '');
window.close();//false

open(location, '_self').close();//false
```

Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m, Firefox also has the problem.

Please help...

[Console option screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rohKD.png)

Answer (score 3):

You should store your opened window in a variable.

```
var popup = window.open(location, '_blank', '');
popup.close();
```

EDIT: Opening in _self does not work since you open a new page in the same screen, you might want to do _blank like i've edited.